# SQL query to pivot data in below table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sqlite, relational-database

I've Attendance Catlog Table as follow,

[image: Catlog Table]

As an example illustrated in above image, 
There are 4 students in class having roll number 1,2,3,4.
Three Teachers named PNT, SGP and DAP have taken attendance of same class at the time of corresponding lecture.
Above table shows Total Absency of each student with respect to each teacher.

I want to generate output as follow,

[image]

This table illustrate total absency of each student under the lecture of corresponding teacher.

How to get such result from given table?

---

DDL and sample Data :

```
create table mytable ( TeacherID varchar(3), RollNo number, Total_Absency number);
insert into mytable values('PNT', 1, 0);
insert into mytable values('PNT', 2, 4);
insert into mytable values('PNT', 3, 0);
insert into mytable values('PNT', 4, 1);
insert into mytable values('SGP', 1, 2);
insert into mytable values('SGP', 2, 1);
insert into mytable values('SGP', 3, 1);
insert into mytable values('SGP', 4, 1);
insert into mytable values('DAP', 1, 1);
insert into mytable values('DAP', 2, 1);
insert into mytable values('DAP', 3, 1);
insert into mytable values('DAP', 4, 0);
```

Comment: Looks like an excercise you're supposed to do :) Have you tried it already ? Show us what you tried and where you are stuck.  As a hint,  PIVOT is what you will need to achieve this

Comment: I edited your qustion to add DDL and sample data as  (Oracle) `insert` commands. You should always provide data in such format.

Comment: You have tagged your question with conflicting tags : mysql, oracle, and sqlite are different RDBMS. Please tag your question properly.

Comment: // mysql, oracle, and sqlite are different RDBMS. Please tag your question properly.// --> My question is regarding sql queries, so any expert in the topic of suggested tags can help me. Hence I tagged mysql, oracle, sqlite etc

Comment: // Looks like an excercise you're supposed to do :) Have you tried it already ? Show us what you tried and where you are stuck. As a hint, PIVOT is what you will need to achieve this //

--> I'm new to pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Oracle, use the `PIVOT` clause :

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT TeacherID, RollNo, Total_Absency FROM mytable
)
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(Total_Absency)
  FOR TeacherID
  IN ( 'PNT', 'SGP', 'DAP' )
)
ORDER BY RollNo
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=105085c56139f390680f079f0fe8f3a2)** :

```
 
ROLLNO | 'PNT' | 'SGP' | 'DAP'
-----: | ----: | ----: | ----:
     1 |     0 |     2 |     1
     2 |     4 |     1 |     1
     3 |     0 |     1 |     1
     4 |     1 |     1 |     0
```

---

With other RDBMS, the general solution is to use condition aggregation :

```
SELECT
    RollNo,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TeacherID = 'PNT' THEN Total_Absency END) AS PNT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TeacherID = 'SGP' THEN Total_Absency END) AS SGP,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TeacherID = 'DAP' THEN Total_Absency END) AS DAP
FROM mytable
GROUP BY RollNo
ORDER BY RollNo
```